# Extending Express Response.render() type definition with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, express

I'm attempting to get some more intelligent typing in my Express project but am having trouble extending the `Response.render` function.

```
import { Response } from "express";
import { Product } from "../models/Product.interface";

export interface ProductListResponse extends Response {
    render: (view: string, options?: { products: Product[] }) => void;
}
```

The origin definition looks like:

```
render(view: string, options?: object, callback?: (err: Error, html: string) => void): void;
render(view: string, callback?: (err: Error, html: string) => void): void;
```

When I try to compile this I get

```
src/routes/product.interface.ts:13:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'ProductListResponse' incorrectly extends interface 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.
  Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
    Type '(view: string, options: { products: Product[]; }) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (view: string, options?: object, callback?: (err: Error, html: string) => void): void; (view: string, callback?: (err: Error, html: string) => void): void; }'.
      Types of parameters 'options' and 'callback' are incompatible.
        Property 'products' is missing in type '(err: Error, html: string) => void' but required in type '{ products: Product[]; }'.

13 export interface ProductListResponse extends Response {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/routes/product.interface.ts:14:37
    14     render(view: string, options: { products: Product[] }): void;
                                           ~~~~~~~~
    'products' is declared here.


Found 2 errors.
```

I thought I could just overwrite the definition of `render` by extending the base interface but apparently that isn't true. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) `render` definition in the express's Response type. Then, redefine your render function:

```
interface ProductListResponse extends Omit<Response, 'render'> {
  render: (view: string, options?: { products: Product[] }) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `.render()` method overload signatures of the `Response` interface to your custom `ProductListResponse` interface.

```
import express, { Response } from 'express';

interface Product {}

export interface ProductListResponse extends Response {
  render(view: string, options?: { products: Product[] }): void;
  render(view: string, options?: object, callback?: (err: Error, html: string) => void): void;
  render(view: string, callback?: (err: Error, html: string) => void): void;
}

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res: ProductListResponse) => {
  res.render('index', { products: [] });
});
```

Or, use [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)

```
import express, { Response } from 'express';

interface Product {}

export interface ProductListResponse {
  render(view: string, options?: { products: Product[] }): void;
}

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res: ProductListResponse & Response) => {
  res.render('index', { products: [] });
});
```

TypeScript version: `4.4.4`